# Round up to the nearest 50,000 in PHP

Tags: php, rounding

Is there a way to round up to the nearest 50,000 in PHP?

I've investigated round, but the docs don't suggest a way to do this, and it looks as though it is only for rounding up/down to the nearest numner. Thanks.

Comment: ...and negative numbers?

Comment: Maybe doubling the number, rounding it to the nearest 100000 (2nd parameter -5) and halving it again?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
/**
 * Round a number up to the nearest multiple of $n.
 *
 * @param int $int  Number to round.
 * @param int $n    Round to the nearest $n.
 *
 * @return int
 */
function round_up_to_nearest_n($int, $n) {
    return ceil($int / $n) * $n;
}
echo round_up_to_nearest_n(74268, 50000); //Outputs 100000
```

Divide by the number you want to round against, do the rounding, then multiply by it again.

Comment: Although in this case the question probably is asking for `ceil()`.

Comment: @MadaraUchina - Many thanks, this (subsituting `round()` for `ceil()`, as suggested in the comments, worked a treat.

Comment: @DavidGard: Note that this would probably behave unexpectedly for negative numbers!

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - Negitive numbers will not be an issue for me here, but noted for future refernece. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
$number = ceil($value / 50000) * 50000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$number = "78921";
$round = round($number / 50000) * 50000;
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I found out before posting this, `round()` will round both up and down, when it is always up that I need. It was the `ceil()` function that I was unaware of that solved this for me.

Comment: @DavidGard Sorry, I hadn't noticed the "round up" ;)