# Round to the nearest tenth?

Tags: php, rounding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Round up to the nearest 50,000 in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745332/round-up-to-the-nearest-50-000-in-php)

I have this, 52.52 and I want it to become 52.5. How would I do that in PHP? I tried round() but did not work. Thanks.

Comment: Did you read [the documentation for `round()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)?  Second parameter is the desired precision.

Comment: yep, also tried most of the answers here in stackoverflow but none worked for me.

Comment: See my answer below -- number_format also does the trick. Both rounds and sets decimal places at the same time.

Comment: well instead of downvoting, you should cast your answers instead. tsk!

Comment: @CHiRiLo: Downvoting is a measure of how clear or researched your answer. It's clear, but not researched at all. I found a duplicate in a couple of seconds (which works on the same principle, and the answer given works well). The documentation for `round()` clearly shows an easy solution for your specific problem. So forgive me if my vote stands.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
round($num, 1);
```

should round $num to the nearest tenth (the second argument specifies the precision, or the number of digits after the decimal it should round to)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$x = number_format('52.52', 1)
```

[Documentation is here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Comment: I think you want the second argument to be `1`, but I also think `number_format` truncates rather than rounds properly.

Comment: No, it does round properly -- but thank you for the catch on the argument. I also saw it after testing my answer, but appreciate the extra eyes - +1.